# Create many distribution plots using For loop with seaborn

Tags: python, for-loop, seaborn, distribution

I'm trying to create many distribution plots at once to few different fields. I have created simple for loop but I make always the same mistake and python doesn't understand what is "i".

This is the code I have written:

```
for i in data.columns:
    sns.distplot(data[i])
```

> KeyError: 'i'

I have also tried to put 'i' instead of i, but I get error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

I b elieve my mistake is something basic that I don't know about loops so understand that will help me a lot in the future.

My end goal is to get many distribution plots (with skewness a kurtosis values)  at once without writing each one of them.

Comment: One of your columns contains data in `string` format.

Comment: Nope, if you want to select only numeric columns use something like `numeric_data = data._get_numeric_data()` and do your loop over `numeric_data`.

Comment: @zipa understand, is there any way to run for loop but to tell it to skip some columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run only over numeric columns use:

```
numeric_data = data._get_numeric_data()
for i in numeric_data.columns:
    sns.distplot(numeric_data[i])
```

Comment: _get_numeric_data() is a really good way to get numeric values. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you cannot make a distplot from a string column. If you want to ignore string columns, you can check for each column as you are iterating through them as such:

```
for i in data.columns:
    if(data[i].dtype == np.float64 or data[i].dtype == np.int64):
          sns.distplot(data[i])
    else:
          //your code to handle strings.
```

I ran a simple test based on what you needed and it works fine on my machine. Here is the code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = [1,2,3,4]
c = [1,4,6,7,4,6,7,4,3,5,543,543,54,46,656,76,43,56]
d = [43,3,3,56,5,76,686,876,8768,78,77,98,79,8798,987,978,98]
sns.distplot(a)
e = [a,c,d]
for i, col in enumerate(e):
    plt.figure(i)
    sns.distplot(col)
plt.show()
```

In your case, it would be like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for index, i in enumerate(data.columns):
        if(data[i].dtype == np.float64 or data[i].dtype == np.int64):
              plt.figure(index)
              sns.distplot(data[i])
        else:
              //your code to handle strings.
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you all, I did it and it runs but still I don't get different plots ,but one plot that doesn't really show the distribution

Comment: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  binned = fast_linbin(X, a, b, gridsize) / (delta * nobs)
C:\path\Reutk\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\nonparametric\kdetools.py:34: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  FAC1 = 2*(np.pi*bw/RANGE)**

Comment: You have accepted an answer above. Your issue has been resolved now, I assume?

Comment: well I still have some issue with this but not relates to the 'i' anymore

Comment: Have a look at this post. It is pretty similar to what you are trying to achieve?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55770326/matplotlib-loop-through-axes-in-a-seaborn-plot-for-multiple-subplots

Comment: The result is similar but the dataframe is a bit different . I am not sure why my loop creates only one plot and not many

Comment: Check the updated code that I posted. Let me know if it works

Comment: I want something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50940283/show-metrics-like-kurtosis-skewness-on-distribution-plot-using-seaborn-in-pytho  but I don't understand tthe second part of the code